# How to setup a solution which has projects for winforms and web?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, design-patterns

In my solution I have a few projects:

- A core project. This project contains all my classes and interfaces
- A Winforms project
- A Web project

A key feature of the application is to dynamically generate controls. I have a class with an enum, and based on an enum value a particular control must be returned. So I've created a factory in the core project like this:

```
public IControl Create(Enum enum)
{
    switch(enum)
    {
      case "enum.A":
        return new CheckBoxControl();
      case "enum.B":
        return new RadioControl();
    }
}
```

Ass you might have guessed, I have custom controls. They all inherit from an Interface (IControl). But in this case, CheckBoxControl and RadioControl are WinFroms controls.

Now, these controls resides in the core project. I don't want this, because it is a core library and I want this library to be platform independent.

I want the winforms controls in a WinCore project and the WebControls in a WebCore project. The problem is, How can I return the right controls from the core project?

Both, the WebCore and WinCore project need a reference to the core project, because the core project contains my entities. This means, that I can't set a reference from the core the web- or wincore project.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would do that:

- **.Core** *should be an assembly containing business*.
- **.Shared** *should be an assembly containing infraestructure, base classes and interfaces that are platform and technology-independent - so this will let you referene it in any project avoiding unwanted dependencies -.*
- **.Web** *should be the assembly containing web-oriented functionality*
- **.Web.Forms** *should be the assembly containing Web Forms and Web Controls only*.
- **.Windows** *should be the assembly contaning Windows-oriented functionality.*
- **.Windows.Forms** *should be the assembly contaning Windows Forms and Controls only.*

Having such assembly structure, IControl interface should be in **.Shared** assembly and this should be referenced by **.Core**, allowing code to add IControl instances without needing technology-specific dependencies.

In addition, this solution is enough to let **.Windows**, **.Windows.Forms**, **.Web** and **.Web.Forms** reference **.Core** and/or **.Shared**.

---

<strike>UPDATE:</strike>

It's just a suggestion, but why are you using an enumeration in your factory? You could do that:

```
public TControl Create<TControl>() where TControl : IControl, new()
{
    IControl control = new TControl();

    // Control initialization work

    return control;
}
```

What do you think?

*Nevermind that, it was just a suggestion because maybe, with some refactoring, you could use this kind of factory method, but I can understand this is far from your current implementation. Concentrate better in my answer :)*

---

UPDATE 2:

How inversion of control can help you in your problem?

In fact, if you register inversion of control components, you're going to access them by type or by some unique identifier.

Let's say you've the `IControl` interface (the service) and WindowsTextBox and WebFormsTextBox both implementing `IControl`. In your configuration file you're goint to have two components, which have both same service type (the interface) and two different implementations and these will be marked with two different identifiers:

- WindowsTextBox is IControl, with identifier **WindowsTextBox**.
- WebFormsTextBox is IControl, with identifier **WebFormsTextBox**.

Now you've both controls registered in your inversion of control container, and you can use own-API component retrieval factory like this:

- `IoCFactory.GetComponents<IControl>()`. You want all **IControl** implementations in current inversion of control's container - not recommended in your case! -.
- `IoCFactory.GetComponent<IControl>("WindowsTextBox")`. You want the **IControl** implementation called "WindowsTextBox".

In the second case, which is our focus now, you get an object typed as **IControl**, meaning you can access to its common members (properties, methods, events...).

Where's the point of inversion of control in your problem? Note you're using a **factory** class that would be placed in a shared library so you can use it anywhere, and same for **IControl** interface.

Right, I guess you need concrete control instances. You can do two things:

- Just play with **IControl** instances and wherever, in a technology-specific logic, cast it to its concrete type - for example, *WindowsTextBox* - and go on.
- Create as many interfaces that concrete more **IControl**, so some logic can access to some properties and methods that are closer to the concrete control feature set. *An example of that would be a **ITextBox** interface and get any inversion of control component by this more concrete interface in the same way as I explained above*.

I believe I gave enough hints in order to get an idea of how my solution structure and assembly organization, plus inversion of control, can give you such technology independence that you're looking between and within your project's layers! ;)

Comment: And where do I place my factory which returns my controls?

Comment: If you factory creates instances of IControl, you can place it in **.Shared** or **.Core**, but I'll prefer to say that definitively **.Shared** is the best place, because you don't want a "core" dependency in your UI.

Comment: Your update: I am not that familiar with generics. I don't understand it completely.

Comment: My factory creates concrete classes. So I need (I think) 2 factories: a wincore factory and a webcore factory which both returns concrete win- or web controls

Comment: I'm declaring a factory method that will return a IControl implementation, because **where** is specifying that TControl will be of IControl and it must have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Right, right, no problem with that: TControl accepts ANY implementation of IControl. You can do that + `Factory.Create<WinFormTextBox>()` or `Factory.Create<WebFormTextBox>()` with no troubles! :D

Comment: Ah, and as TControl is a generic parameter, you're going to get concrete classes by using this factory method.

Comment: But when I use it that way, I already know which concrete control I need. The meaning of my factory is that the factory determines which control I need. In your case, the control is already known.

Comment: In that case, you can know the type and you can use reflection in order to call this factory method with the appropiate generic argument.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Do you suggest to create factory which returns a Type? And then, resolve that type using reflection and then create an instance?

Comment: No, I mean you can call factory method with reflection. For example `(WinFormsControl)factory.GetType().GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(WinFormsControl)).Invoke();`. You can create a Create overload that that takes the type directly and reflection work is done in its body, so you can do that: `(WinFormsControl)factory.Create(typeof(WinFormsControl));`. Actually, I don't know your project's requirements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this. Why should I call my factory using reflection? And where/how do I get my concrete control?

Comment: Really nevermind this suggestion. I don't know how your object graph is, and maybe this isn't the right solution for you. Pay more attention to the answer itself :)

Comment: Okay, anyway thanks for the effort, but I still don't know how to solve my problem haha.

Comment: Try my proposal!! Is there something you're not understanding in my answer?

Comment: But in your case, I already know the concrete class, and the meaning of the factory is that he returns the concrete class, based on the enum value.

Comment: ? Nevermind the "update" part of my answer. But anyway, have you heard about inversion of control?

Comment: Then what is your suggestion? I have heard about it, but I don;t see how I can use it here. It is something like dependency injection, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Let me answer you in the answer itself.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to Google more about IoC, maybe I'll understand your second update better :) Thanks for everything :)

Comment: I m wondering... When I register the controls to IoC, I need this instance to be alive as long as I need the controls, right? This means, I have to create a lot of extra properties/overloading constructors which accepts the IoC.

Comment: I don't understand you at all.. But you don't need to implement any specific thing for IoC. You just need an interface or abstract class (the service) and an implementation (the class implementing the service).

Answer (score 0):

Add a Controlmanager to core with a method RegisterControls. Webcore calls the Controlmanager.RegisterControls method. The main app only talks to core

Comment: I like the idea of such a ControlManager. Didn't thought about that, but where should I register those controls?

Comment: main executes webcore.Register which calls core.register

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different factory in the WinForms project and in the Web project. Create a `IControlFactory` interface that is implemented in both factories, and instantiate the appropriate type of factory in each project.

Comment: I've thouight about this one, but this is not going to work, because the concrete factories are in the wincore and webcore, so the core project needs to know about these concrete classes, which means I have to set a reference from the core to the web and wincore, and this is not possible.

Comment: No, it doesn't to know that. The core project shouldn't know about the concrete implementations, it should only know about the interface. The concrete implementation should be instantiated in the web and winforms projects, and passed to the core project

Comment: Okay, but I have multiple concrete classes which implement the same interface. If the factory an interface, how should I know which concrete class to create?

Comment: The Web project will create a WebControlFactory, and the WinForms project will create a WinFormsControlFactory. In both case the factory will be passed to the core project as a IControlFactory.

Comment: I think that I know what you mean, but is not going to work in my situation. I have a mediator object with a method called `GetControls()`. This mediator is placed in the core project. In this method I create a factory object and call the `Create` method with a parameter (so the factory can create an object based on the parameter). When the factory has created an instance, the method returns this object. So, I (think) can't use your suggestion, or can I?